# Get accuracy metric from leaderboard function when using H20 AI

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, automl, h2o.ai

I am running a binary classification model using H2O autoML. I have explicitly told autoML to treat this as a classification model with the following line of code.

```
# This line of code turns our int variable into a factor.
# This is necessary to tell H2O that we want a classification model
feature_data['Radius'] = feature_data['Radius'].asfactor()
```

After running H20 autoML for a minute and then using the following line of code;

```
lb = aml.leaderboard
lb.head()
lb.head(rows=lb.nrows) # Entire leaderboard
```

I got the output in the screenshot below
[image: Leaderboard output]

As you can see, the metrics used for classification are AUC and logloss but what I want to see is accuracy. What should I add to get such an output?

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but maybe will solve your primary problem - get good ML pipeline. You can try to check MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised - It can't optimize Accuracy, but you will be able to check Accuracy for every model because of automatic report generation (in Markdown format).

Comment: @pplonski Thank you! Was experimenting with MLJAR as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the leaderboard allows you to sort using accuracy as a metric. The following lines of code and text have been directly taken from the [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/sort_metric.html?highlight=h2oautoml):

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 30, sort_metric = "logloss")
```

> For binomial classification choose between `AUC`, `"logloss"`, `"mean_per_class_error"`, `"RMSE"`, `"MSE"`.

Comment: It is admittedly very strange for MSE & RMSE to be used in *classification* settings.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply assign `"accuracy"` as a sorting metric while building h2o aml model like:

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 30, sort_metric = "accuracy")
```

It will publish the model based on accuracy in ascending order from top to bottom.